# Is there any equivalent to a rejection region in Bayesian estimation methods?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value

I'm flipping through Bayesian estimation literature and I'm trying to find something that is similar to the rejection region in frequentist approaches.

Intuitively, by setting the rejection region to a large quantity say 1 - 5% you can require there to be a large preponderance of evidence before you reject the null hypothesis.

How do you build such conservative leanings in Bayesian estimation methods -- where it seems you select either the maximum posterior probability or perhaps try to find a parameter which maximizes the likelihood function?

Comment: Note that when you refer to "rejection region", you are writing of a hypothesis test, but when you switch to "Bayesian estimation methods", you are writing of point estimation.  These are not the same thing, and phrases like "conservative leanings" don't really apply.  Are you interested in a Bayesian analogue to the classical hypothesis testing framework?

Comment: yes -- is there a Bayesian analog that biases the status quo over the new claim

Comment: 1. That's not the same as classical hypothesis testing.  2. Writing loosely, the role of the prior in Bayesian statistics is to record information about the "status quo" beliefs / available information in such a way that it can be integrated into the estimation procedure, hence automatically "biasing" the results towards the status quo.  The posterior estimates are a mix of the prior information and the data.  I'm not entirely sure what you want other than this...

Comment: ah ofcourse yes -- the prior establishes the status quo -- thank you that helped.

Comment: For an introductory article that sets frequentist and Bayesian notions side by side, see this blog post: http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-bayesian-new-statistics-finally.html